# An exception throwing when I query db from Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Something strange here with Meteor 1.2.1 and Iron Router 1.0.12.

```
Router.route('/news/:_id', function() {
    this.render('l_basic');
    console.log (newsCollection.findOne().title);
});
```

This works perfect. I’ve got the title of my last post in the console.

But there is an unwanted exception too. No matter where I would place database query: into the main router function, to the onAfterAction or any other hook. Doesn't matter, if I'll surround it with `if (this.ready())`.

If I comment console.log statement, no exception appears.

This is what I get in console. I've completely broken my head, trying to find out what is going on here.

```
Exception in callback of async function: http://localhost:3000/app/both/router.js?4bb8a45e172aaff7cfe3c5a6bff0f87a62d217d0:17:59
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:418:35
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:27
onRerun@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:515:13
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:418:35
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:27
onRun@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:499:15
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:418:35
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:27
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:442:7
_runRoute@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:538:17
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:848:27
route@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:705:19
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:418:35
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:27
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:365:18
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:27
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:442:7
http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:385:21
_compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:349:36
Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:237:18
autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:588:34
http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:383:17
nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:615:13
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:382:19
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:1692:22
onLocationChange@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:1776:33
_compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:349:36
Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:237:18
autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?7776276660c988c38fed448d8262b925dffb5bc3:588:34
start@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:1769:43
http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?c564289eeaa191561eba900052037432ebfcbe4a:972:21
withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:971:21
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:428:54
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:27
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:365:23
```

Comment: What's the exception's description? Have you tried just logging the result of `newsCollection.findOne()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Woods I found that my initial code printed both the exception and the title just because of reactivity. And everything I had to do is wait for subscriptions from iron:router.

```
Router.route('/news/:_id', function() {
    this.render('l_basic');
    console.log (newsCollection.findOne().title);
}, {
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('news');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some [helpful documentation](https://meteorhacks.com/subscription-manager-for-iron-router/) on managing subscriptions for Iron Router.

I'm pretty sure your `findOne()` is returning `undefined` at this point, which means your findOne().title is going to throw an exception.  You'll want to use `waitOn()` to get your subscriptions ready before querying data.

Comment: No, it is not. I'm getting the correct value for title in my console right after the exception. I tried to wrap my console.log statement with `if (this.ready())` to be sure that subscriptions are ready. Nothing changed.

Comment: Stephen, you were right. My initial code printed both the exception and the title just because of reactivity. And everything I had to do is just wait for subscriptions.